# Using Async/Await when grabbing multiple documents from Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

All examples i can find show how to use async await when grabbing a single Firestore document.
How can i use async await when grabbing multiple documents from Firestore?

In Javascript i find it to be very straight forward but in Swift i just cant get it to work at all. I've tried using Try, Task, Dispatch and completion handlers.

```
func fetchData() async {
        //Grabb all data 
        let test = await Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            var tempUsers = [UsersProfile]()
            if documents.count > 0 {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let user = UserProfile(data: data)
                    tempUsers.append(user)
                }
            }
            self.allusers = tempUsers
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        //Do something after grabbing all data...
    }
```

Comment: If you're using async/await, don't provide a completion callback. In the marked duplicate, look at the code under "Using async/await (Swift 5.5)". I found this with a simple web search for "stack overflow firestore get documents swift async await"